# Get Parent property of network adapter device from c#

Tags: c#, winapi

I need to get the Parent property of network adapter device from c# program

Please find the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaPXO.png)

Tried below code but the property "Parent" is not available

List mappingIpDeviceIds = new List();

```
        Console.WriteLine("Reading Id and IP address...");
        ManagementObjectSearcher adapters = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionStatus = 2");

        foreach (ManagementObject item in adapters.Get())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject setting in item.GetRelated("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
            {
                var relationships = setting.GetRelationships();
                var name = setting["Caption"].ToString();

                
                string[] defaultIPGateway = (string[])setting.GetPropertyValue("DefaultIPGateway");
                string[] compterips = (string[])setting.GetPropertyValue("IPAddress");
                string dhcpserver = (string)setting.GetPropertyValue("DHCPServer");

                foreach (ManagementObject win32PnPEntity in item.GetRelated("Win32_PnPEntity"))
                {
                    var x = win32PnPEntity.Properties;

                    foreach (var prop in x)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("::: PROPERTY NAME ::: " + prop.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("::: PROPERTY VALUE ::: " + prop.Value);
                    }
                }

                MappingIpDeviceId mappingIpDeviceId = new MappingIpDeviceId();
                string deviceid = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID");
                string deviceid1 = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("ProductName");

                string[] devicenames = deviceid.Split(new Char[] { '\\' });
                foreach (string dn in devicenames)
                {
                    mappingIpDeviceId.OWLIP = dhcpserver;
                    mappingIpDeviceId.ComputerIP = compterips[0];
                    mappingIpDeviceId.DeviceId = dn;
                    mappingIpDeviceIds.Add(mappingIpDeviceId);
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: you should try to put the code as text not by images. Then the community can reproduce the problem

Comment: Added code for better understanding

Comment: Which line in your presented code cause error or not working as you expected? And what property do you want to get?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT , I wanted to get the "Parent" property which is shown in the screenshot

Comment: @user1837843 The screenshot is not available.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, Can you please click on the "here" link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can refer to:

1. Using PowerShell command [`Get-PnpDeviceProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/get-pnpdeviceproperty?view=win10-ps): `Get-PnpDeviceProperty -KeyName 'DEVPKEY_Device_Parent' -InstanceId 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`
2. Use `CM_Get_Parent`. "[Determining the Parent of a Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/determining-the-parent-of-a-device)".

Comment: Han Thank you soo much for your response will try and let you know

Comment: I was able to get using the Powershell command "Get-PnpDeviceProperty". Thank you once again @Rita Han

Comment: @user1837843 Glad to help. :)